# What is a good templating engine?

Tags: c#, xml, json, xslt, ironpython

What is a nice templating engine to use in C#? I have XML or JSON as structured datasource. This data needs to be presented to users on the web in strict XHTML.

I've been using XSLT mostly, but maybe there are more or better options?

It needs to be used in C# or IronPython.

Comment: No matter what you're doing, there's always a better option than XSLT...

Comment: @cxfx: What a nonsensical statement.

Comment: Jokes sometimes use nonsense to derive their comedic value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) is great.  I also like the [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/), which is primarily for ASP.NET MVC, but can be used on its own (the download includes a good example).

Comment: Spark sound interesting! Is it easy to implement standalone and with XML as source to format?

Comment: Yes, there's a good standalone demo in the download, and you could use LINQ-to-XML to prepare your source data.  You might also want to look into Xpark - http://whereslou.com/2009/03/23/using-xparkexe-to-transform-xml

Comment: nice, thanks for the tips! i've read about the spark engine before for mvc, but it's also cool in my situation! ;) i'll try it!

Comment: I really like Spark - I use it in MVC apps as the view engine and for email templates, it's great being able to use the same for both.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Apache Velocity Engine
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html

Comment: You probably mean [NVelocity][1]?

  [1]: http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/